# Ошибка IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(1,101):
    k = str(i)
    print(k[5])
else:
    print('Цикл окончен')
```

Как из цикла вывести только одно (в этом примере 5-ое) число?
Я получил ошибку

> ```
> > print(k[5])
> IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

Comment: Что значит выдернуть, какое число и откуда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,101):
    k = str(i)
```

Значит, сначала значением `i` будет `1` и значением `k` будет `"1"`.

Теперь `k` строкой длины `1`. Символы строки индексированы от нуля, значит `k[0]` будет "1" и применение положительных индексов (т. к. `k[1]`, `k[2]`, ...) бессмысленно.

```
    print(k[5])
```

Что такое `k[5]`? Это шестой символ строки `k`. Но такого символа не существует - в строке `k` только *один* символ! **Здесь и ошибка.**

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

> Попробуй заменить "print(k[5])" на "if i == 5: print(k)"

Comment: Зачем `k`? Почему не просто `if i == 5: print(i)`

Comment: После того совета ,я так и сделал ;)

Comment: @S.Nick Извините конечно, что оттрываю вас от важных дел. А где тот комментарий на который ссылается ТС в ответе?

Comment: @0xdb он почему-то удалил комментарий

Comment: Значит поправте ответ, как будто его и не было.